# Is there a way for two users to simultaneously use the same Lightroom catalog?

Tags: lightroom, workflow

I recently hired a friend to help me edit some pictures in Lightroom, but we need to use the same catalog. Is there a way for both of us to use the catalog simultaneously on two different computers, make edits, and have the changes synchronize between our computers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because of the internal database you can't really just merge the libraries.

If you can export parts of the library and re-integrate that, it would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Wish it had support for it though.

Comment: You can achieve a fairly efficient simultaneous multi-user Lightroom workflow if you have your [Lightroom catalog under revision control](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20287/28016) and use the export/import to merge changes made simultaneously.